# Nested tables: Insert values into specific columns of nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

I have a question regarding insert query for a nested table. I have an object like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_animals as OBJECT (
   row_id INTEGER,
   animal_id INTEGER,
   attr1 VARCHAR2(30),
   attr2 VARCHAR2(30),
   attr3 VARCHAR2(30)
 );
```

I have a table type like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_animals_tab IS TABLE OF obj_animals;
```

Nested table is contained in this:

```
CREATE TABLE animals 
(
     animal_id INTEGER,
     animal_ptr obj_animals_tab
)
 NESTED TABLE animals_ptr STORE AS obj_animals_tab;
```

How do I insert into (row_id,animal_id,attr1) columns or (row_id,animal_id & attr3) columns in the nested table using dynamic SQL?

I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO animals(animal_id,animal_ptr(row_id,animal_id,attr3))
VALUES(1,obj_animals_tab(obj_animals(1,1,'4')));
```

This threw me an error: Missing comma. Can you tell me a way to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement must be like this:

```
INSERT INTO animals (animal_id, animal_ptr)
     VALUES (1, obj_animals_tab(obj_animals(1,1,'4')));
```

In order to update existing values you can use this syntax:

```
UPDATE 
   (SELECT t.animal_id as animal_id_T, obj.animal_id as animal_id_OBJ, 
      attr1, attr2, attr3 
   FROM animals t
      NATURAL JOIN TABLE(obj_animals_tab) obj)
SET attr3 = 'xyz'
WHERE animal_id_T = 1
   AND animal_id_OBJ = 1;
```

Maybe it is not very smart to use `animal_id` in both table and object type.

Comment: any idea how syntax would look like if I need to insert values into the columns I need? For instance, I don't want value for attr1. I want it only for  row_id, animal_id, attr3. I need to specify them as null for attr1 & attr2: INSERT INTO animals(animal_id,animal_ptr) VALUES(1,obj_animals_tab(obj_animals(1,1,null,null,'4')));

Comment: No I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO animals(animal_id,animal_ptr(row_id,animal_id,attr3))
VALUES(1,obj_animals_tab(obj_animals(
row_id => 1,
animal_id => 1,
attr3 => '4'
)));
```

Try this out. working for me.